# Which gtk method I have to use to get temporary path in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gnome, glib

How can I get the temporary directory path in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flocks,

Thanks for taking your time but what i am expecting is from the gnome link.

http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/unstable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html

using the API g_get_tmp_dir() we can have the location of temp directory

Answer (score 5):

On most Unix-like systems, you'd be looking for `/tmp`. If that's not quite the answer you were after, you should specify *which* bit of Ubuntu you're talking about.

Certain applications will allow you to specify where their temporary files are put (such as with the `TMP`, `TEMP` or `TMPDIR` environment variables) but a lot of stuff would break under UNIX if `/tmp` didn't exist, so it's safe just to use that. If you want to make it configurable, in your code, you'd use something like the function `getTmpDir()` in the following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *getTmpDir (void) {
    char *tmpdir;

    if ((tmpdir = getenv ("TEMP")) != NULL)   return tmpdir;
    if ((tmpdir = getenv ("TMP")) != NULL)    return tmpdir;
    if ((tmpdir = getenv ("TMPDIR")) != NULL) return tmpdir;

    return "/tmp";
}

int main(void) {
    const char *xyzzy = getTmpDir();
    printf ("Temporary directory =  %s\n", xyzzy);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs, in my CygWin environment (I have both `TEMP` and `TMP` set to this value):

```
Temporary directory =  /cygdrive/c/Users/Pax/AppData/Local/Temp
```

That's pretty much what the GLib [`g_get_tmp_dir()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-tmp-dir) call does, though possibly in a different order.

Of course, if you wanted to use an application-specific environment variable, you could put that before the others thus:

```
const char *getTmpDir (void) {
    char *tmpdir;

    if ((tmpdir = getenv ("XYZZY_TMP")) != NULL)   return tmpdir;
    if ((tmpdir = getenv ("TEMP")) != NULL)        return tmpdir;
    if ((tmpdir = getenv ("TMP")) != NULL)         return tmpdir;
    if ((tmpdir = getenv ("TMPDIR")) != NULL)      return tmpdir;

    return "/tmp";
}
```

Or even take out some or all of the "standard" ones. But you should pretty much *always* fall back on `/tmp` if the user hasn't configured anything.

Comment: ya that's what i am expecting. I want to get that path programmatically using gtk or glib which ever feasible.

Comment: Err, you don't have to get it programatically. It's `/tmp`. It's (sadistic administrators notwithstanding) _always_ `/tmp`. If you're coding in C: `char *tmpdir = "/tmp";` will do it just fine :-) You can affect certain applications (like the `TMPDIR` variable in `bash`) but a lot of things will break if `/tmp` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at [how Python does this](http://code.python.org/hg/branches/py3k/file/b9fdd92bb086/Lib/tempfile.py#l127),  and there doesn't seem to be any specific UNIX interface to do so.

They just try, in sequence:

1. The environment variables `TMPDIR`, `TEMP`, and `TMP`
2. `/tmp`
3. `/var/tmp`
4. `/usr/tmp`

Given that Python was written by people a lot smarter than I am, I'd be willing to bet this is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

There is an environment variable TMPDIR which can set the location of the temporary dir, most programs respect this, if it's not set it will default to /tmp (or /var/tmp)

Answer (score 0):

From the command line:

```
$ tempfile | xargs dirname
/tmp
$ TMPDIR="/mnt/tmp" tempfile | xargs dirname
/mnt/tmp
```