# How to get a temporary file name?

Tags: c, unix, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I've seen some posts relating to my question, but none that address it completely.  I need to create a file in the standard temporary directory and after I'm done writing to it, move it to a different location.  The idea is that the file is considered temporary while being downloaded and permanent after downloading completes.

I'm attempting this by calling either [mkstemp](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/mkstemp.3.php) or [tmpfile](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/tmpfile.3.php), then [rename](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/rename.2.php) after I'm done writing to it.  However, I need the full path of the file to call rename, and apparently getting the file name from a file descriptor (returned by mkstemp) or FILE * (returned by tmpfile) is no trivial process.  It can be done, but it's not elegant.

Is there a system call that will create a temporary file and provide me with the name?  I know about [mktemp](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/mktemp.3.php) and related calls, but they either aren't guaranteed to be unique or are deprecated.  Or perhaps there is a better way to accomplish creating, writing to, and moving temporary files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like [`mkstemp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html) is actually the way to go.

```
int fd;
char name[] = "/tmp/fileXXXXXX";
fd = mkstemp(name);
/* Check fd. */
```

After this call you have a valid descriptor in `fd` and the name of the associated file in `name`.

Comment: You are correct, and I need to be more thorough when I read the documentation.  Call me OCD, but I used the info at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790471/how-can-i-get-the-temporary-directory-path-in-ubuntu) to get the temporary folder instead of simply hard-coding "/tmp";

Comment: If you are creating a file in /tmp/ and then you are planning to move the file to specific location say "/home/<user>/ then it will take long time to cp or move and it will be even worst if /tmp and /home/ were in different partition area; so better create file in /home/<user>/fileXXXXX and rename it to /home/<user>/file.

Comment: What is the final filename?

Comment: @DonScott See the answer again: "and the name of the associated file in `name`".